# Join data frame into one in r

Tags: r, dataframe, join, dplyr

I have 4 data frames that all look like this:

| Product 2018 | Number | Minimum | Maximum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 56 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 42 | 12 | 16 |
| 3 | 6523 | 23 | 56 |
| 4 | 123 | 23 | 102 |
| 5 | 56 | 23 | 64 |
| 6 | 245623 | 56 | 87 |
| 7 | 546 | 25 | 540 |
| 8 | 54566 | 253 | 560 |

| Product 2019 | Number | Minimum | Maximum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 56 | 32 | 53 |
| 2 | 642 | 423 | 620 |
| 3 | 56423 | 432 | 560 |
| 4 | 3 | 431 | 802 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 | 6 |
| 6 | 4523 | 43 | 68 |
| 7 | 555 | 23 | 54 |
| 8 | 55646 | 3 | 6 |

| Product 2020 | Number | Minimum | Maximum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 | 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 342 | 4 | 16 |
| 3 | 223 | 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 13 | 4 | 12 |
| 5 | 2 | 4 | 7 |
| 6 | 223 | 7 | 8 |
| 7 | 5 | 34 | 50 |
| 8 | 46 | 3 | 6 |

| Product 2021 | Number | Minimum | Maximum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 234 | 3 | 5 |
| 2 | 3242 | 4 | 16 |
| 3 | 2423 | 43 | 56 |
| 4 | 123 | 43 | 102 |
| 5 | 24 | 4 | 6 |
| 6 | 2423 | 4 | 18 |
| 7 | 565 | 234 | 540 |
| 8 | 5646 | 23 | 56 |

I want to join all the tables so I get a table that looks like this:

| Products | Number 2021 | Min-Max 2021 | Number 2020 | Min-Max 2020 | Number 2019 | Min-Max 2019 | Number 2018 | Min-Max 2018 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 234 | 3 to 5 | 23 | 2 to 5 | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2 | 3242 | 4 to 16 | 342 | 4 to 16 | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 3 | 2423 | 43 to 56 | 223 | 3 to 5 | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 4 | 123 | 43 to 102 | 13 | 4 to 12 | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 5 | 24 | 4 to 6 | 2 | 4 to 7 | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 6 | 2423 | 4 to 18 | 223 | 7 to 8 | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 7 | 565 | 234 to 540 | 5 | 34 to 50 | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 8 | 5646 | 23 to 56 | 46 | 3 to 6 | ... | ... | ... | ... |

The Product for all years are the same so I would like to have a data frame that contains the number for each year as a column and joins the column for minimum and maximum as one.

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this. You are trying to join several dataframes by a single column, which is relatively straight forward using `full_join`. The difficulty is that you are trying to extract information from the column names and combine several columns at the same time. I would `map` out everying you want to do and then `reduce` the list of dataframes at the end. Here is an example with two dataframes, but you could add as many as you want to the list at the begining.

```r
library(tidyverse)

#test data
set.seed(23)
df1 <- tibble("Product 2018" = seq(1:8), 
              Number = sample(1:100, 8), 
              Minimum = sample(1:100, 8),
              Maximum = map_dbl(Minimum, ~sample(.x:1000, 1)))

set.seed(46)
df2 <- tibble("Product 2019" = seq(1:8), 
              Number = sample(1:100, 8), 
              Minimum = sample(1:100, 8),
              Maximum = map_dbl(Minimum, ~sample(.x:1000, 1)))


list(df1, df2) |>
  map(\(x){
    year <- str_extract(colnames(x)[1], "\\d+?$")
    
    mutate(x, !!quo_name(paste0("Min-Max ", year)) := paste(Minimum, "to", Maximum))|>
      rename(!!quo_name(paste0("Number ", year)) := Number)|>
      rename_with(~gsub("\\s\\d+?$", "", .), 1) |>
      select(-c(Minimum, Maximum))
  }) |>
  reduce(full_join, by = "Product")
#> # A tibble: 8 x 5
#>   Product `Number 2018` `Min-Max 2018` `Number 2019` `Min-Max 2019`
#>     <int>         <int> <chr>                  <int> <chr>         
#> 1       1            29 21 to 481                 50 93 to 416     
#> 2       2            28 17 to 314                 78 7 to 313      
#> 3       3            72 40 to 787                  1 91 to 205     
#> 4       4            43 36 to 557                 47 55 to 542     
#> 5       5            45 70 to 926                 52 76 to 830     
#> 6       6            34 96 to 645                 70 20 to 922     
#> 7       7            48 31 to 197                 84 6 to 716      
#> 8       8            17 86 to 951                 99 75 to 768
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar answer, but includes `bind_rows` to combine the data.frames, then `pivot_wider` to end in a wide format.

The first steps strip the year from the Product XXXX column name, as this carries relevant information on year for that data.frame. If that column is renamed as `Product` they are easily combined (with a separate column containing the `Year`). If this step can be taken earlier in the data collection or processing timeline, it is helpful.

```
library(tidyverse)

list(df1, df2, df3, df4) %>%
  map(~.x %>%
        mutate(Year = gsub("Product", "", names(.x)[1])) %>%
        rename(Product = !!names(.[1]))) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  mutate(Min_Max = paste(Minimum, Maximum, sep = " to ")) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Product, names_from = Year, values_from = c(Number, Min_Max), names_vary = "slowest")
```

**Output**

```
  Product Number_2018 Min_Max_2018 Number_2019 Min_Max_2019 Number_2020 Min_Max_2020 Number_2021 Min_Max_2021
    <int>       <int> <chr>              <int> <chr>              <int> <chr>              <int> <chr>       
1       1          56 1 to 5                56 32 to 53              23 2 to 5               234 3 to 5      
2       2          42 12 to 16             642 423 to 620           342 4 to 16             3242 4 to 16     
3       3        6523 23 to 56           56423 432 to 560           223 3 to 5              2423 43 to 56    
4       4         123 23 to 102              3 431 to 802            13 4 to 12              123 43 to 102   
5       5          56 23 to 64               2 2 to 6                 2 4 to 7                24 4 to 6      
6       6      245623 56 to 87            4523 43 to 68             223 7 to 8              2423 4 to 18     
7       7         546 25 to 540            555 23 to 54               5 34 to 50             565 234 to 540  
8       8       54566 253 to 560         55646 3 to 6                46 3 to 6              5646 23 to 56
```